# Permissions for edit scheduled reminder

Tags: permissions, scheduled-reminders

I want to give a staff person the permission to create and edit scheduled reminders, but I do not want to give them full administrator rights. How can I configure that person's permissions for this?  We are using CiviCRM v 5.57.4 on Drupal 9.

Comment: It's not going to be setting a UI permission option without customization or a feature improvement. It's located here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/blob/master/CRM/Admin/Page/ScheduleReminders.php#L121

Comment: And here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/blob/master/CRM/Admin/Form/ScheduleReminders.php#L67